# iPhone Dev Center Website error 413 overloaded with cookies

Tags: iphone, website, safari, http, cookies

I started receiving an error when attempting to log into the iPhone Dev Center web site "413 Request Entity Too Large". At first I thought they were having issues but when I couldn't find any reference to the issue by other people, I started looking at my system (Mac Leopard).

I discovered that Safari was holding a ton of cookies for devcenter. I must have had a cookie for every reference documentation page I had looked at in their online help. Obviously this was the issue as cookies are sent to the server along with the request and there were so many cookies that the total amount of data exceeded the allowable max. Thankfully Safari allows me to multi-select cookies and delete otherwise I would have started having Diablo flashbacks and need to ice my wrist.

Has anybody else encountered something like this? Is there a way to stop dev center from burying me in cookies? Do I just need to do some cookie-cleaning once a week and move on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the answer was "deal with it".